# SASS for loop creating list item grid, having problems incrementing rows

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to create a grid of list items, I have 10 items and want to position them absolutely in sets of 2. I can set the left position fine using modulus but I tripping up on how I can increment the top position so each row is an additional 20% top. Can anyone advise on what I need to do? I tried adding in a row and top value counter but I think my logic for this is messed up. Currently all top values get set as 0, is it because Im not setting `$topValue` as a percentage or am I messing this up?

**SASS**

```
$total: 10;
$inc: 0;

    @for $i from 1 through $total {
        $rowCount: 0;
        $topValue: 0;
        li:nth-child(#{$i}) {

            top: $topValue;

            $rowCount: $rowCount + $rowCount;

            @if $rowCount >= 2 {
                $rowCount: 0;
                $topValue: $topValue + 20;
            }

            @if $i % 2 == 0 {
              left: 50%;
            } @else {
              left: 0;
            }
        }


    }
```

Pen: http://codepen.io/styler/pen/IAkzy 
SASS: http://sassmeister.com/gist/a5ee97397eb2a0609ca1

Answer (score 0):

```
$total: 10;
$inc: 0;
$rowCount: 0;

@for $i from 1 through $total {
  li:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    @if $i % 2 == 0 {
      left: 50%;
    } @else {
      $rowCount: $rowCount + 1;
      left: 0;
    }
    top: ($rowCount - 1) * 20%;
  }
}
```

Fiddle: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/umojy

Comment: This kind of works although it increments every element by 20% http://codepen.io/styler/pen/IAkzy

Comment: Sorry misunderstood what you're trying to achieve. So you want the first two li's top:0%, the next two top:20%, etc.?

Comment: yeah thats it 1+2 top:0, 2+3 top:20 etc etc